# Pod presets vs ConfigMaps in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Both seems to achieve the same - configure a pod at build time.

Can anyone please explain me what is the difference between the two?
Maybe also give a simple 1 use case example of each after, if you think that's going to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pod preset is more scalable and powerful than configmaps/secrets for injecting common information into Pods.

A Kubernetes cluster may contain hundreds of Pods. Many of these Pods share common constructs like Environment Variables, ConfigMaps, Secrets etc. For instance, in case of microservices using MySQL, we need to inject MySQL credentials as K8s Secrets in the pod. If cluster has 100 microservices( not so uncommon) , we would need to add following section in all 100 pod's configuration.

This is terribly inefficient and error prone. Pod Preset help us avoid this by injecting common information in multiple Pods so that we put all common information in one place.

```
    env:
      - name: SECRET_USERNAME
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: mysecret
            key: mysql-username
      - name: SECRET_PASSWORD
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: mysecret
            key: mysql-password
```

From the pod preset design [doc](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/service-catalog/pod-preset.md#motivation).

> **Motivation**:
>
> Consuming a service involves more than just connectivity. In addition
>   to coordinates to reach the service, credentials and non-secret
>   configuration parameters are typically needed to use the service. The
>   primitives for this already exist, but a gap exists where loose
>   coupling is desired: it should be possible to inject pods with the
>   information they need to use a service on a service-by-service basis,
>   without the pod authors having to incorporate the information into
>   every pod spec where it is needed.
>
> **Use Cases**
>
> 1. As a user, I want to be able to provision a new pod without needing to
>      know the application configuration primitives the services my pod will
>      consume.
> 2. As a cluster admin, I want specific configuration items of a
>      service to be withheld visibly from a developer deploying a service,
>      but not to block the developer from shipping.
> 3. As an app developer, I
>      want to provision a Cloud Spanner instance and then access it from
>      within my Kubernetes cluster.
> 4. As an app developer, I want the Cloud
>      Spanner provisioning process to configure my Kubernetes cluster so the
>      endpoints and credentials for my Cloud Spanner instance are implicitly
>      injected into Pods matching a label selector (without me having to
>      modify the PodSpec to add the specific Configmap/Secret containing the
>      endpoint/credential data).

Comment: 1. Is it then correct to wrap it up like ConfigMaps are the primitives, whereas the PodPresets are an abstraction on top of them (+ some more)?

2. ConfigMaps configure pods explicitly at individual pod level, whereas a PodPresets allow shared configuration on groups of pods? <br>
I see that PodPresets use selectors in their API object, whereas the ConfigMaps don't.

Comment: From the design doc: `PodPresets did not progress out of alpha since 1.6. They were removed in 1.20`